# Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Trying to send message from background.js to content script but for some reason chrome is saying that it is unable to establish connection

I tried to disable all other extensions and even attempted at running the code block out side of the for loop and if/else statement but still no help.

Background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {





  chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {


    var allTabs = [];

    // Query all tabs in the current window
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      // Iterate through the array of Tab objects
      tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
        // Store tab information in the 'allTabs' array
        allTabs.push({ id: tab.id });
      });
    
      // Now, 'allTabs' contains information about all tabs in the current window
      console.log(allTabs);
    });  
    
    
    //Creates variable CurrentTabId
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      var currentTabId = tabs[0].id;

      console.log("Current Tab ID: " + currentTabId);
    
      // Iterate through the 'allTabs' array 
      for (let i = 0; i < allTabs.length; i++) {
        //Matches each ID in array against current tab ID
        if (allTabs[i].id !== currentTabId) {
            console.log(allTabs[i].id + " Not current")   
            // Trying to send message to background script
            var messageToContentScript = {
              greeting: "Hello from the background script to a specific tab!"
            };
            
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(messageToContentScript);
          
                
        } else {
          
          console.log(allTabs[i].id + " Current");
          var messageToContentScript = {
            greeting: "Hello from the background script to a specific tab!"
          };
          
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage(messageToContentScript);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Manifest.js

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Focus: Pomodoro Timer App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Pomodoro timer which helps you keep focus on your stuyding !",
  "icons": {
    "48": "48.png",
    "128": "128.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],

  "action": {
  "default_title": "Focus" 
  
},

"background" : { 
  "service_worker": "background.js"
},

"permissions": [
  
"activeTab",
"https://*/*",
"http://*/*",

"tabs"
]

}
```

Content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(message.greeting); 
});
```

Comment: which line of your code throws the error?

Comment: Line 1 of background.js

Comment: ahh, chromes useless error stack strikes again

Answer (score 0):

This is because `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` cannot be used to send message to content script tabs. According to the document of  [Chrome extension runtime messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20extensions%20cannot%20send%20messages%20to%20content%20scripts%20using%20this%20method.%20To%20send%20messages%20to%20content%20scripts%2C%20use%20tabs.sendMessage.), you should use `tabs.sendMessage` instead. Hope this can help!

Comment: Didnt work for me.

Comment: Could you please provide the updated code?